# c# SendKeys.SendWAit Cant write full path text

Tags: c#

I create snippet to click button to open file dialog and fill the full path file, for example D:\a.png but keep getting error like the screenshot below

[image]

meanwhile this is the sample code that i use

[image]

been try "D:\a.png" but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry seem it's because to fast, adding delay 1 second and all work fine :D my false